# Method of proof confusing between Vector space and Linear Transformation.

Tags: vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I'm confusing about the way to determine the Vector space and the Linear Transformation.

My knowledge is the way to determine whether the map given is Linear Transformation by proving this : $T(\alpha A+B) = \alpha T(A)+T(B)$. This is my way to show that if it's linear trans, or not.

But for the Vector Space, I saw my friend, he proof the vector space by doing this; Suppose $S_1,S_2 \in S$ then show if $\alpha S_1+S_2 \in S$ Thus, $S$ is a vector space.

I wonder why mine in Linear Transformation or his in vector space are looked the same.

Do mine or his method wrong ? or we both wrong. And if either or both wrong, what's the correct way?

Thank you

Comment: If I understand what you're saying correctly, both of your approaches are correct.  The definitions are *similar* and *related*, but are ultimately slightly different.

Answer (score 0):

This is because linear transformations are precisely the maps that respect the vector space structure. For instance, if $V$ is an $n$-dimensional vector space, then $V$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$. Such an isomorphism corresponds to giving a basis for $V$. In other words, $V$ is completely determined by a basis, because every vector is a linear combination of the basis vectors.

Even if you aren't familiar with bases, the point is that linear structure is essentially determined by how we can add vectors together. If we want a map $T: V_1 \to V_2$ to preserve this structure, we would naturally require
$$
T(av + bw) = aT(v) + bT(w).
$$

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct.

Linear transformations are "nice" mappings between vector spaces. They are "nice" because they *preserve* the vector space structure.

A linear transformation preserves both (1) vector addition: $T(v+w)=T(v)+T(w)$ and (2) scalar multiplication: $T(\alpha v)=\alpha T(v)$.

We want our "nice" maps between vector spaces to do so because a vector space carries these two operations: (1) vector addition and (2) scalar multiplication.

Likewise, subspaces are vector spaces hiding inside vector spaces. For a subset to be a sub*space*, we need it to respect the same operations as its parent space. Thus we need (1) closure under vector addition: $S_1, S_2 \in S$ implies $S_1+S_2 \in S$ and (2) closure under scalar multiplication: $S_1 \in S$ implies $\alpha S_1 \in S$.

So our "nice" subsets should respect both operations: (1) vector addition and (2) scalar multiplication.

So the definition of a linear transformation and the subspace test are on the surface quite similar -- not surprisingly since they both deal with the same abstract algebraic object: a vector space.

It might be interesting to note that because of these similarities one can always swap a subspace test for checking a map is a linear transformation. It is not too difficult to show that every subspace can be viewed as both the kernel and range of some linear transformation. Since kernels (i.e. nullspaces) and ranges are subspaces, if you can verify that your subset is the kernel (or the range) of a linear transformation, you'll have verified that it is a subspace.